# Custom Exceptions Routing to DLQ in ActiveMQ Using Spring JMS

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am using broker activemq 5.5.1 and Spring JMS for messaging. I have requirement as below

A) I want to push the messages into DLQ only when respective exception occurs. Currently as per my understanding, any exceptions thrown from Message Listeners are moved to DLQ after specified retry parameters. Does ActiveMQ provide this facility and how ?

B) I have to control Retry mechanism based on class level meaning No-Retry for custom exceptions. For example, if there is an Instance of MyException class thrown, I should not retry those messages such that it should not go to DLQ. Please advise

-----EDIT-----------

I tried to restrict retry attempts when JMSRedelivered is true. But this message though the exception is thrown only once for retry it is not adding to DLQ. Here is my test code. I am using activemq 5.5.1

```
 public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        if (message != null)
            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                String messageContent = ((TextMessage) message).
                if (message.getBooleanProperty("JMSRedelivered")) {
                    throw new CustomException1();
                } else {
                    throw new CustomJMSException("Retry Logic");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JMSException jmsex) {

    } catch (CustomException1 e) {
        System.out.println("Exception Caught");
    } catch (CustomJMSException e) {
        throw new CustomJMSException("Exception thrown");
    }


Spring Configuration:

<bean id="redeliveryPolicy1" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
    <property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="1000" />
    <property name="redeliveryDelay" value="1000" /> 
    <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="5" />
    <property name="useExponentialBackOff" value="false" />
    <property name="backOffMultiplier" value="1" /> 
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is catch (and ignore or log) exceptions you want to ignore and re-throw those that you want to route to the DLQ.

Or, you could use [spring-retry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/index.html) instead of activeMQ's mechanism; it has policies to determine which exceptions should be retried and a `RecoveryCallback` that allows you to decide which exceptions to absorb or re-throw.

Comment: I can catch those exceptions that should not move to DLQ, however, please let me know if these will also be retried multiple times according to redelivery policies? If yes, could we handle it any other way than spring-retry (which i will explore).

Comment: The only thing you can do without spring retry is one redelivery attempt - test the `JMSRedelivered` header. If you want to ignore the delivery after more than 2 attempts, you need stateful spring-retry or some other mechanism to keep track of the number of attempts.

Comment: I tested setting JMSRedelivered header, however, once the exception is thrown from listener, there will be no control returning back. I have a requirement to stop retry on second attempt. If my understanding is wrong or if you think my implementation would have been incorrect, please advise

Comment: Simply catch the exception if `JMSRedelivered` is `true`.

Comment: I tried to restrict retry attempts when JMSRedelivered is true. But this message though the exception is thrown only once for retry it is not adding to DLQ. I have a requirement to add poison message to DLQ as well. Please advise. I have added my test code here

Comment: Gary, could you please advise on this

Comment: Not really; it's not clear what you are saying. When you throw an exception the message will be rolled back and redelivered/DLQ'd according to your ActiveMQ configuration. When you catch the exception, the message will be removed from the queue and won't go to the DLQ.

Comment: Currently I have configured the redelivery parameter for 5 times. As I observed the error message is only pushed to DLQ when the retry happens for 5 times. This means that though I throw an exception on first instance when JMSRedelivered is true it is not pushed to DLQ, instead it is getting dequeued.

Comment: But that's what you asked for - "I should not retry those messages such that it should not go to DLQ." - if you catch the exception on the redelivery and you can "eat" the exception on the second attempt (no DLQ) otherwise it will be tried 5 times, then DLQ'd.

Comment: Correct! my bad. I had a change in requirement such that in case of throwing custom exception, only the first message of retry should be to DLQ and ignore rest of the other attempts. This means when there is a custom exception i have retry once and push to DLQ and ignore other 4 attempts.

Comment: You can always publish the message to the DLQ yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1) Yes ActiveMQ has out of box feature where the messages which fail (after certain retries ofcourse) are automatically moved to a queue named `ActiveMQ.DLQ`,this is the default dead letter queue for all queues in the broker